How to get this impulse response properly in MATLAB?
I am studying book Statistical Digital Signal Processing and Modeling Book by Monson H. Hayes
In chapter 4, example 4.3.2 of approximation, impulse response of a system is shown , which is also shown in attached snap, but i am  confused how to find it in MATLAB, i have used command impz but not getting same values in has x^(n)
I have also attached snap of my MATLAB code



Initial comment
As a start, let me note that you have used incorrect coefficients in your Matlab script. You have used $\left[ 1, -1.5, -1.5 \right]$ while the last coefficient should be $1.5$ instead.
“Solution”
What you can (and possibly should) do is ask Matlab for a specific number of coefficients. With the impz() function, you can easily specify that number as an input argument. Replicating your script with the appropriate changes (noted with capitalised comments) we get
num = 1;
den = [1, -1.5, 1.5]; % CORRECTED THE LAST COEFFICIENT
[h, t] = impz(num, den, 6); % LAST ARGUMENT IS THE NUMBER OF COEFFICIENTS
disp(h); % SHOW THE COEFFICIENTS

This gave the following numbers for me:
 1.0000
 1.5000
 0.7500
-1.1250
-2.8125
-2.5312

which seem to be the same (down to rounding and numerical accuracy) with the ones provided in the book.
